# LibGDX ,super Mario tutorial

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So I am following the Brent Aureli tutorial of super Mario ,and even after pulling his code from git https://github.com/BrentAureli/SuperMario/blob/Mario-Tutorial-26/core/src/com/brentaureli/mariobros/Sprites/Mario.java

My character does not jump ! even though it runs left and right ! 
so it was brought to my attention that LibGDX was using a new version so i tried

```
 private TextureRegion marioStand;
    private Animation<TextureRegion> marioRun;
    private Animation<TextureRegion> marioJump;
```

This is the constructor

```
Array<TextureRegion> frames = new Array<TextureRegion>();
        //get run animation frames and add them to marioRun Animation
        for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            frames.add(new TextureRegion(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("little_mario"), i * 16, 0, 16, 16));
       marioRun = new Animation(0.1f, frames);

        frames.clear();

        for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            frames.add(new TextureRegion(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("big_mario"), i * 16, 0, 16, 32));
        bigMarioRun = new Animation(0.1f, frames);

        frames.clear();

        //get set animation frames from growing mario
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("big_mario"), 240, 0, 16, 32));
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("big_mario"), 0, 0, 16, 32));
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("big_mario"), 240, 0, 16, 32));
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("big_mario"), 0, 0, 16, 32));
        growMario = new Animation(0.2f, frames);
        frames.clear();
        for(int i = 4; i < 6; i++)
            frames.add(new TextureRegion(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("little_mario"), i * 80, 0, 16, 16));
        marioJump = new Animation(0.1f, frames);
        frames.clear();





 public TextureRegion getFrame(float dt){
 case JUMPING:
               // region = marioIsBig ? bigMarioJump :  marioJump;
                region = (TextureRegion) marioJump.getKeyFrame(stateTimer);
                break;
            case RUNNING:
                region = (TextureRegion) (marioIsBig ? bigMarioRun.getKeyFrame(stateTimer, true) : marioRun.getKeyFrame(stateTimer, true));
                break;
```

Comment: So yeah you set an animation for jumping. But I dont see any code for the logic of it. Somewhere you need to press a key and move the player up and down again. Òther then that, is your method `getFrame` even compiling? You are using `case` without a `switch`.

Comment: yes my getFrame is compiling . the game runs fine ,except the character does not jump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the original code and cannot find the actual jump mechanics anywhere in `Mario.java`. I can see if the vertical velocity of mario is other then `0` it should run the jumping animation. So perhaps, if the falling physics are in place and you run off a cliff you will see the jumping animation playing.

So I guess you just need to apply some force to the character. Something along the lines of `b2Body.applyForceToCenter(0f,10f,true)` or `b2Body.setLinearVelocity(0f, 10f);`. This could go into the render method when you check for a key press or if you are using a `InputProcessor` it can go in the `keyDown` method.

Comment: public void handleInput(float dt){
       
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP) ){
            player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, .4f), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        }